# Understanding photo libraries when migrating from iPhoto to Photo

Tags: catalina, photos, photos.app, migration, macos

I recently updated an outdated OS to Catalina, in which the *iPhoto* app was replaced by the *Photos* app.
In *HD/Users/User/Images*, I now find three different folders :

- *iPhoto-Library* (Migrated Photo Library) - 45GB
- *iPhoto-Library* (Photos Library) - 40GB
- *Photos-Library* (Photos Library) - 50GB - contains some 150 more photos than *iPhoto-Library* - Not sure if the *Photos-Library* was created automatically or by me.

I know I can open one of these libraries at a time in the *Photos* app. I also know that in the Finder, I can right-click and access the structure of these libraries. I noticed that they do not have the same folder structure.

My goal is to obtain one Photos-Library containing all the photos contained
in the three libraries (including a check so as not to lose possible non-duplicates).
Where can I get more information about how to proceed?

On this Stackexchange, I found several questions related to my issue, but I haven't found the exact solution. Some links :

- [How to duplicate-check between iPhoto Library and Photos Library *and* move non-duplicates from iPhoto -> Photos?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189852/how-to-duplicate-check-between-iphoto-library-and-photos-library-and-move-non)
- [If I've migrated from iPhoto to Photos, can I safely delete the migrated photo library?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/247258/if-ive-migrated-from-iphoto-to-photos-can-i-safely-delete-the-migrated-photo-l)

**EDIT**

I have added the file sizes in the list above.

The second linked question indeed answers my question more or less. It seems I can delete the *iPhoto-Libraries* and keep the *Photos-Library*.

I still do not understand the difference in file size, and would like to see which photos appear in the *Photos-Library* but not in the *iPhoto-Library* (maybe I have imported them before noticing there were different libraries). However, it seems there is no easy way to compare two libraries, as only one library can be opened at a time (except using external software, cf. the first linked question).

Comment: Which part of your question is not answered by the second link?

Comment: I would like to know what is the difference between the three libraries and why they have different sizes. Furthermore, I want to be sure which one of the three I can keep without losing photos (after being able to compare the three libraries).

Comment: I understand that. But isn't this exactly what the answer on the second link explains?

Comment: If not, please explain in more detail what you are looking for. Also add some detail about the libraries (size, number of photos, timestamps etc.).

Comment: @nohillside OK. I have added my more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Some more information about the structure can be found [here](https://sixcolors.com/post/2015/02/the-hard-link-between-photos-and-iphoto/). The three folders you see all reference to the same set of image files on your Mac, using hard links.

The 150-photos difference MAY be due to one of these reasons:

- Your Photos library already had some photos before you migrated iPhoto library (More likely).
- You had RAW and JPEG pairs for some photos. iPhoto counted each pair as one photo, but in migration they exported separately, increasing the count (Less likely).

The Photos library *should* be the superset containing all your photos, but the only confirmatory test I can think of is to extract the file lists from the SQL databases of those three folders and compare them.